# SVG sprite doesn’t work after update to iOS 9.3

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I store all my SVG icons in one sprite and use it like that:

```
<ion-nav-title>
    <svg class="dropShadow">
        <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#logo1"></use>
    </svg>
</ion-nav-title>
```

It worked perfectly on iOS 9.2, but on iOS 9.3 all icons are missing.
Is that a bug? Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hmmm having the same problem on Safari for iPad. Looking at your class 'dropShadow' helped me understand why only one set of my SVGs were not showing up: '-webkit-filter: drop-shadow'.

Once I removed the drop-shadow the SVGs were back.

If you add the drop-shadow to a parent element it will work just fine i.e:

```
<figure class="dropshadow"><svg></svg></figure>
```

Comment: Unbelievable. Come on, Safari, get it together!